# I cannot find ''Android SDK Tools" in my Android SDK settings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I tried everything, but I cannot find a way to add Android SDK tools. I have platform tools and build tools, but in the list (apperarance and behaviour > system settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools) i don't find SDK tools. And I do not know how and where I can install them. Thanks!

UPDATE: I found them under obsolete, but do i want the 'obsolete' SDK tools? Are there any not obsolete ones? Flutter doctor does not find any errors now though but is this the way to do this?

Update2: i was asked to add pictures. I would close this question because everything seems to be working fine, but I am still confused why the only SDK tools i have are 'obsolete' and it still does not work without them.

[image]

Comment: add some screenshots, futher read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @josepraveen i am sorry for the late edit, it worked fine with obsolete tools. still confused if that's how it should be though